# How do I make an attribute that will show the size of my polygon

Tags: arcmap, fields-attributes, feature-layer, arcgis-collector

Im trying to Create a feature layer for the scaring (Area burned) for hazard reduction burns on Arcdesktop and would like to have an attribute that shows the size of the polygon used.

Eg: I finish mapping the scarred area on collector that is 10 hectares and another area neighbouring it that is 5 hectares then when i click the layer I'd like it to generate the size without having to enter it in manually.

Comment: Just saw you mentioned Collector...are you talking about Collector for ArcGIS or another collector?

Comment: You could use arcade and show this in the popup https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#area

Answer (score 2):

You could store the polygon shapefile in a Geodatabase. A Geodatabase will create a field in the polygon feature called "Shape_Area", which will store the geometry area of the polygon feature. This will be calcualted automatically when you finish editing.

The units for the this field are whatever you have set the feature class coordinate system.

If you are simply looking to populate a field with an area, you can create a field in the shapefile called "BurnArea", make it "Double". Right click this field and select the "Calculate Geometry" and choose area and the units you want the area to be calculated in. you will then be able to click the feature and see the area an an attribute. This is "manual" but you can calculate the area for more than one polygon at a time.

Answer (score 0):

@keagan-allan gave two great options.

Assuming you are working in arcMap: If you want to add area using Model Builder or an arcPy script, you can use the "Add Geometry Attributes" geoprocessing tool. See: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm

The "Add Geometry Attributes" tool allows you to define the units for the area. This is helpful if you want to calculate the area using units that differ from the coordinate system of the input features. For example, the layer uses meters as the liner unit, but you'd like to calculate the area in Acres. You could always use the default and then convert the units using the field calculator later, but this saves you a step. If you do this, be sure to record what units your area field uses in your meta-data.

Note from the documentation:

> If the fields already exist in the input features, the values in
>   those fields will be overwritten.